# cannot display json data returned from jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

can somebody please tell me, how can I display json data returning from the ajax call. I am new to this.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
cache: false,
timeout: 5000
```

});

```
//String.prototype.toJSON;

var the_object = {};


function concatObject(obj) {
    strArray = []; //new Array
    for (prop in obj) {
        strArray.push(prop + " value :" + obj[prop]);
    }
    return strArray.join();
}
//var ntid = "hhsh";
//document.writeln("httpRequest.responseText");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").ajaxStart(function() {
        alert('Triggered ajaxStart handler.');
    });
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            //data: "{'ntid':'john'}",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //processData: false,
            url: "Testing.aspx/SendMessage",
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            },
            success: function(result, txtStatus, httpRequest) {
                alert(txtStatus);
            //$('#status').html(httpRequest.responseText);
                //the_object = result;
                $('#status').html(concatObject(result));
                //$('#status').html(the_object);
                //alert("hello" + concatObject(the_object));
                //document.writeln(concatObject(the_object));
            }
        });
        //alert(concatObject(the_object));
        //$('#status').html(concatObject(the_object));

    });
});
```

above is the js file. should i need to do something on asp file directly to display it. if yes, then how? please reply me soon. i m stuck here and unable to display data here. Its only diplaying this line:

toJSON value :function (key) { return this.valueOf(); }

Comment: Could you format this code with the 'Code Sample' button in the editor?

Comment: Can you please format your code so it is more readable? wrap it in <pre><code>Code Here</code></pre>

Comment: Can you please post the json response?

Answer (score 0):

Your result is most likely rooted with a property named d.  Try modifying your success to use result.d;

This is usually a security measure that has to do with exploits which target a JSON collection with single root parent.

Comment: Thanks marc, i try result.d but no gain. any other idea?